# Сессия корзины в интернет-магазине django rest framework + vuejs

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuex

Пишу свой первый интернет-магазин, хочу хранить в сессии корзину товаров не авторизованного пользователя. Где должна осуществляться работа с сессией на фронте (vuejs) или на бекенде (django rest)? Цена и его количество на вариант товара может изменяться.

Примеры и ссылки приветствуются.

Comment: Решили вопрос , у меня такая же проблема , скиньте ссылку )))

Comment: Как вариант: храните id товаров в браузере пользователя, а когда пользователь открывает свою корзину, из базы данных грузите товары ищя их по id. В такое случае информация у товаров всегда будет актуальной